# Catagorized hierarchy menu for PAGES!

Tags: menus, widgets, pages, title

Yes, I am a noob at all this so please excuse my ignorance! So, for the past couple of days, I've been searching for a drop down page menu widget, but I would like to have the pages separated into "labeled" catagories. I don't have pages that require any hierarchy, so I don't have or want a parent page to catagorize by. Basically, I want to be able to enter a label/title for the group that will show on the menu and when you click or hover on the label, the pages designated to that label will drop down. I noticed you can catagorize posts and links, but not pages. Does such a widget exist??

Answer (score 1):

Such a widget does not exist.
You say you don't want to use parents, but that is my advise.
Then just make a menu for it.
If you know how you could make it yourself.
A plus of this would be that you get the 'category name' of the parent in your permalink.

An other idea would be to create a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) and enable categories there.
It would be better organized.
Still the menu would be best coded yourself using [wp_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Awesome sauce... looks like wp_query would be a good solution. I have a repository of resource pages and need a better way to organize them, and it looks like this will give me more control and options. Thanks for the help!